# “I did my homework twice three times.”

Tags: adverbs

Is “I did my homework twice three times” grammatically and semantically correct? It means I did my homework six times. (twice on Friday, twice on Saturday and twice on Sunday)

Comment: Usually, we would say: twice on three separate occasions. "twice three" is hard to use.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The sentence you gave would most likely be understood as saying that on three occasions you did your homework twice. If you wanted your hearer to do the multiplication you could perhaps use "I did my homework two times three times" or "I did my homework two threes of times". Both are quite awkward constructions. Anther possibility is "Twice three times I did my homework." This is also awkward unless you are writing poetry.

In speech you might make it clear you want the product by saying "twice three" with no gap, and long gaps before and after.

The problem is that "I did my homework twice" is meaningful and the sentence can be interpreted as saying this happened "three times". The same problem does not occur with "Give me twice three cabbages".

Answer (score 1):

It is at least very confusing.

In this context, "Doing my homework twice" probably means doing the same homework twice ("I did my homework, but then my computer crashed and I had to do it again, so I did my homework twice") But on its own "I did my homework twice" is unclear, and probably requires some explanation of how that happened.

And then how could it happen three times!? Surely there must be some story here.

If you just mean "I did two pieces of homework on Friday, two more on Saturday and two more on Sunday", your expression does not clearly say that.

You could use the long sentence in the previous paragraph if you need all that detail, otherwise all you need to say:

> I did six pieces of homework.

Comment: I mean like there are six trees and I wonder if expression like two three trees (2x3) is valid like two thousand trees (1000x2)

Comment: That is a different context and a different question. No you don't say two three trees.  English uses base ten counting, not base 3.  Saying two thousand is part of the counting system, not a mathematical calculation.

Comment: You can say two dozen trees if there are 24 or two score trees if there are 40.

Comment: In _Kubla Khan_, Coleridge refers to 'twice five miles of fertile ground' - but nobody would dream of using an expression like that in ordinary conversation.

Answer (score 0):

@James K's answer is correct, but I thought I'd add some additional comment.

Your example sentence would be largely unremarkable if a comma were added.

> I did my homework twice, three times.

It would be doubly unremarkable if reporting on something extraordinary or unusual in an emphatic way.

> I did my homework twice. Three times!

However, as @James K said, "twice three times" makes little sense and is not idiomatic in the context you gave it..

The purpose of good writing is to avoid ambiguity, so adding extra words would be necessary to convey a clear meaning to the reader/listener.

> I did my homework twice three times last week!

You don't need a comma here, but 'last week' makes it clearer that it is 'doing-homework-twice' that was done 'three times'.

Even then I would say there are better and less ambiguous ways to express it that avoid the stylistically cludgy 'twice three times'.

> Last week I did my homework twice on three separate occasions.